# Android date time parsing

Tags: android, date, simpledateformat

I am trying to parse the following str to Date:

```
2013-10-23T11:00:00EDT
```

I am using follwoing to do so:

```
String TIMEZONE_DATE_TIME_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssz";
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat(TIMEZONE_DATE_TIME_FORMAT, Locale.US).parse(strDate);
```

its working good on most devices but on some it throws the following exception:

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2013-10-23T11:00:00EDT" (at offset 19)
```

Can someone explain why?

Answer (score 1):

Try this code. This may help you to fix the exception

```
SimpleDateTime format = new SimpleDateTime("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssX", Locale.US);
Date date = format.parse(text);

DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ")
                                            .withLocale(Locale.US);
DateTime dateTime = formatter.parseDateTime(text);
```

In fact, there's an `ISODateTimeFormat` class to make this even simpler:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = ISODateTimeFormat.dateTimeNoMillis();
```

Comment: Non of the above options worked on the the device where SimpleDateFormat is failing.